# How to render variable with HTML elements in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Firstly I create a variable `liTagsPagination` with `<a>` elements depending on `sectionsXml` size array. And after that insert that variable into `htmlPagination`. And finally render `htmlPagination` variable with all html content.

But the output in the view is only the content of `liTagsPagination` in plain text. In DOM the `liTagsPagination` is appended to `<ul>` but no as a different element.

```
render() {
 let liTagsPagination = "";
 this.state.sectionsXml.forEach(function(elementSection, indexSection) {
    liTagsPagination += "<li><a id=\"_sectionPage"+ indexSection +"\" className=\"section\">"+(indexSection+1)+"<\/a><\/li>";
 });

 const htmlPagination = (
   <div id="pages-nav-branch" className="col-xs-12 text-center">
       <ul className="pagination pagination-section pagination-sm">
           {liTagsPagination}
       </ul>
   </div>
 );

 return(
    <div>
       {htmlPagination}
    </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `foreach` in render  to create the array of `li` tags. Do not use string concatenation.

```
render() {

    let liTagsPagination= this.state.sectionsXml.map(function(elementSection, indexSection) {
         return <li><a id={"_sectionPage"+ indexSection} className="section">{indexSection+1}</a></li>;
    });

    const htmlPagination = (
      <div id="pages-nav-branch" className="col-xs-12 text-center">
          <ul className="pagination pagination-section pagination-sm">
              {liTagsPagination}
          </ul>
      </div>
    );

    return(
       <div>
          {htmlPagination}
       </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Great approach, whereas there may be other elements that are not mapping in return.

Answer (score 1):

The content of `liTagsPagination` will be displayed in plain text bcoz you are forming a simple string. This will be displayed as string. Rather you should use JSX to generate HTML as other parts of your code is generated by HTML.

You can form JSX instead of HTML which will get your desired behaviour. This will create an array of `li` tags which can be rendered directly.
`key` is important when you are looping to form JSX tags.

```
const liTagsPagination= this.state.sectionsXml.map(function(elementSection, indexSection) {
  return (<li key={indexSection}>
       <a id={`_sectionPage${indexSection}`} className="section">
        {indexSection+1}
       </a>
   </li>);
});
```

If you want to use only HTML, then you have to make use of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` which is not preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering strings inside the JSX language which is causing your problem, you need to change your code to do the following :

```
let liTagsPagination = this.state.sectionsXml.map((element, index) => {
    return (
        <li>
            <a id={ `_sectionPage${index}` }
               className="section">
               { index + 1 }
            </a>
        </li>
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sample you provided, it would be better to just use jsx rather than creating a html string and inserting it.

```
render() {
   const liTagsPagination = this.state.sectionsXml.map(function(elementSection, indexSection) {
      return (
         <li key={indexSection}>
           <a id={`_sectionPage${indexSection}`} className="section">
             {`+(${indexSection+1})+`}
           </a>
         </li>
      );
   });

   const htmlPagination = (
     <div id="pages-nav-branch" className="col-xs-12 text-center">
         <ul className="pagination pagination-section pagination-sm">
             {liTagsPagination}
         </ul>
     </div>
   );

   return(
      <div>
         {htmlPagination}
      </div>
   )
}
```

If however, you do encounter a scenario where you absolutely need to insert an html string, you can use dangerouslySetInnerHtml (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html)

Comment: Same approach that @palsrealm. He answered first, but thanks.